# Programmatically tapping NavigationLink in SwiftUI on push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, swiftui

I have a very simple app displaying a list and each row is a NavigationLink to the detail view. This is a simplified version with what I think are the most important parts:

```
class Element: ObservableObject {
  @Published var id: String
  ...
}

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var elements: [Element]
  ...
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ListViewModel
  @EnvironmentObject private var pushHandler: PushNotificationHandler

  var body: some View {
    List(viewModel.elements) {
      NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(element: element)) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now the app receives push notifications referring to each of the elements by id, i.e. the userInfo dictionary contains one of the ids belonging to an `Element`. What I would like to do now is navigate directly to the `DetailView` when the user taps on the push notification.

I also have a class listening to notification center delegate calls that looks something like this:

```
class PushNotificationHandler: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, ObservableObject {
  @Published var lastNotificationResponseID: String?

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    lastNotificationResponseID = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["id"] as? String
  }
}
```

So far I have discovered that `NavigationLink` can be created with `isActive`, which is a `Binding<Bool>` and which when set to `.constant(true)` pushes the `DetailView` as soon as I start the app.

My problem is - how do I pipe the `lastNotificationResponseID` into the `NavigationLink`'s `isActive` and compare it to `element.id` of the corresponding row so that the correct `DetailView` is pushed when the push is tapped?

Comment: You should use some ObservableObject (which is reference type) to join things together. Next should help (similar task) https://stackoverflow.com/a/63185764/12299030.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a very generic answer that does not help me. As you can see I already have an ObservableObject, and it's exactly the joining of things that I am missing. The link also does not help as I have an array of ObservableObjects which all have to be updated.